# How to find efficient hardware implementation of sbox of lightweight block ciphers?

Tags: encryption

Lightweight block ciphers are usually optimized for compact hardware implementations and sbox values are computed by implementing circuit using basic logic gates(AND, XOR, OR, NOR etc).

What is the method to find an efficient hardware implementation of a 4-bit sbox?

For example, the Sbox of the Piccolo cipher is

[image]

which can be computed in hardware by

[image]

The solution I could think of is "find Algebraic Normal Form(ANF) of all boolean functions, and then make the circuit". But this does not seem to produce a compact representation.

Comment: Seems like schematics by cryptologists are almost as bad as those by physicists ... but for different reasons.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we closed [this exact same question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/426075/how-to-find-compact-hardware-implementation-of-a-4-bit-function) by the same guy 44 minutes ago, which he since then deleted.

Comment: It pains me a bit, however, because hardyrama actully gave a good, more general answer! It would be salomonic to rephase the question to perfectly fit the answer.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I was asked to post question at electrical engineering forum, when i posted here moderators migrated the origanl question also which resulted in duplication. So i deleted the other one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the method to find efficient hardware implementaion of a 4-bit
>   sbox?

finding efficient hardware implementation is by looking on :

- **Multiplicative complexity**: the smallest number of nonlinear gates
- **Bitslice gate complexity**: the smallest number of operations in {AND, OR, XOR, NOT} required to compute this function
- **Gate complexity**: the smallest number of logic gates required to compute this function
- **Circuit depth complexity**: the length of the longest paths from an input gate to an output gate

There are methods used to find efficient implementation  such as SAT solving [ref][source code][1](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/198.pdf) (the sat solver has been applied on Piccolo sbox) and Logic Minimization Techniques [ref](https://ws680.nist.gov/publication/get_pdf.cfm?pub_id=908384) which has been to find bit-slice implementation of AES sbox.
for further reading , I also recommend you to read [SoK: Peigen – a Platform for Evaluation, Implementation, and Generation of S-boxes](https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/209.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

If you have the GF(2) description for the SBOX, you can do the reductions to get to a minimal circuit discussion.  Pulling from a description of how I implemented the [AES S-Box](https://github.com/bpdegnan/aes/blob/master/aes-sbox/documentation/aessbox.pdf), this is the basic method:

\$GF(2)\$  polynomials represent rings of numbers and the logic reductions used in this work are based \$GF(2)\$  polynomials.  The computations on \$GF(2^8)\$ are done by lower order composite field reduction using
\begin{align} 
\label{eqn:GFdecomposition}
GF(2^2)&\rightarrow GF(2)&:x^2+x+1\nonumber \\ 
GF((2^2)^2)&\rightarrow GF(2^2)&:x^2+x+\varphi\\
GF(((2^2)^2)^2)&\rightarrow GF((2^2)^2)&:x^2+x+\lambda \nonumber
\end{align}
where \$\varphi=\{10\}_2\$ and \$\lambda=\{1100\}_2\$.  As previously stated, \$GF(2^2)\$ polynomials can be decomposed to lower-order composite fields where \$n_1x+n_0\$.  Therefore, any binary number, \$k\$, can be split into \$k_Hx+k_L\$.  As an example, for \$k=\{1001\}_2\$, the value \$k\$ is \$k_Hx+k_L\$, resulting in 
\$\{10\}_2x+\{01\}_2\$, which can be further reduced to \$\{1\}_2x+\{0\}_2\$ and \$\{0\}_2x+\{1\}_2\$ as high and low terms.

Given the mathematics, and a few hours, you can get a minimal circuit implementation.